# Calculating days from two dates

Tags: report-viewer2010

So i have a report viewer showing data but in one of my columns i want to show the calculated days based off the previous two columns of dates in an expression property i can apply for the text box. Example of what i am trying to do

8/1/2011     8/19/2011      18 days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(endDate - startDate).TotalDays
```

Substraction on two DateTimes produces TimeSpan object, which has TotalDays property

Or try `DateDiff("d", endDate, startDate)` (for Visual Basic only)

Comment: so if i wanted to check if the endDate is null or not can i still do it within the DateDiff statement?